# How to sort tasks by priority?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

In my schema, I have a table for tasks where one of the columns is priority. In the task model I have assigned the priorities to an enumerable. I am trying to sort them by high priority to low priority. I have been able to sort them from low to high. Please see my code and help me sort them the other way. Thanks.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :assignee, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "assigned_user_id" 

  enum priority: ['whenever', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'immediate']

  self.default_scope {order ('tasks.priority')}
```

Comment: try changing your order statement to order ('tasks.priority DESC')

Comment: Try `self.default_scope {order ('tasks.priority DESC')}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was simply to add `DESC` to the query as such:

```
self.default_scope {order ('tasks.priority DESC')}
```

Another way to do this is to add `.reverse_order` to the end of the query:

```
self.default_scope {order ('tasks.priority')}.reverse_order
```

Both produce identical results